# Alternatives to pytest-watch on python unit test with pytest

Tags: pytest, pytest-cov

I have been trying to watch my tests WITH test coverage without much of a success. My best attempt sofar is to install packaeges `pip install pytest pytest-watch pytest-cov` and run on separate terminals or tabs these commands, below

1. Watch tests: `ptw --quiet --spool 200 --clear --nobeep --config pytest.ini --ext=.py --onfail="echo Tests failed, fix the issues" -v`
2. Coverage: `coverage run --rcfile=.coveragerc -m pytest && coverage report --omit="tests/*,src/main.py,*/__init__.py,*/constants.py" --show-missing`

An alternative to this approach is the shell script below. To run it, run command: `chmod +x watch.sh && ./watch`

```
#!/bin/bash
clear

while true; do
  coverage run --rcfile=.coveragerc -m pytest
  coverage report --omit="tests/*,src/main.py,*/__init__.py,*/constants.py" --show-missing
  
  sleep 5  # Adjust delay between test runs if needed
  clear
done
```

It renders slower compared to command run `ptw`, but outputs exactly what I want. Would you please, provide maybe more effective alternatives than mine?

Thanks. :)